# Can I use the conditional operator like this?

Tags: c++, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

```
!isalpha( str[first] )  ? ( return isPalindrome( str, ++first, last ) ) : return isPalindrome( str, first, --last ) ;
```

I get a syntax error.

Answer (score 6):

That's not allowed, because `return` is not allowed inside an expression; it's only allowed at the top-level of a statement. (Any expression can be used as a statement, but the reverse is not true.) You can write either this:

```
return !isalpha(str[first])
           ? isPalindrome(str, ++first, last)
           : isPalindrome(str, first, --last);
```

or this:

```
if (!isalpha( str[first] )) {
    return isPalindrome( str, ++first, last );
} else {
    return isPalindrome( str, first, --last );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Makes total sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
return !isalpha(str[first]) ? 
       isPalindrome(str, ++first, last) : 
       isPalindrome(str, first, --last);
```